# When to use Cron Job vs. ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, cron, scheduled-tasks

Our team is currently developing a Java application that will have many processing threads that continually run (doing things such as polling from a queue).

Related to this application there are a series of tasks that have to be ran at some pre-determined time periods (once per day, every six hours, etc.).  Some members of our team believe that it would be best to execute these tasks as standalone processes via cron, while others believe that it would be better to just include them within the current application scheduled via Java's ScheduledExecutorService.  Is there a best practice as to when to use cron vs. the internal ScheduledExecutorService, or is it simply a matter of preference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage of using `ScheduledExecutorService` is that you are working with 100% java and thus if you want to upgrade your server/change your machine for some reason then you not need to re-configure cron job. Moreover, ScheduleExceutorService also allows you to use `Callable` hence you can return some results and process them in java.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of using cron is, that your operating team is probably familiar with it, and that you can easily re-schedule or suspend operation without changing and re-deploying the application. (scheduling batch operation is mostly a operating-team task)

Disadvantages are that you either need an interface in your application the cron job can call (like a REST-service), or that cron starts a second VM, running in parallel to your application during execution of the job.

We are currently moving from a Quartz-based internal scheduling to the cron/REST approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would vote on the side of the Single Responsibility Principle:  If the periodic tasks *can* be run as separate processes, independent of the main application, then they *should* be run as separate processes.  If you just throw it all into one big sack, my money says you will regret that decision some day.